# using python to login onto a .jsp webpage

Tags: python, jsp, web

i try to access this page`(http://xx/login.jsp)` using python and do some scrapping later.

```
{<form method = "post" name = "login" action = "llogin.jsp"> 
                <input type = "text" name = "llogin" value = ""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan = "2"><b>Password</b></td><td width = "50px">
                <input type = "password" name = "lpasswd" value = ""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"></td><td>
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login">
                <input type = "reset" name = "reset" value = "Reset"></td>
                </form>
                </tr>
                }
```

the code i wrote (all borrowed from StackOverflow):

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
username = ''
password = ''
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'llogin' : username, 'lpasswd' : password})
req=urllib2.Request('http://xx/login.jsp', login_data)
resp=urllib2.urlopen(req)
data =resp.read()
print data[:]}
```

it ended up printing the login.jsp page

the form method has an action arguement of llogin.jsp should i enter this link or login.jsp(main link) in urllib2.Request.?
on putting llogin.jsp i got the error:

```
There was some error in the request and hence you have been logged out. Inconvenience is regretted. Click to <a href="login.jsp">re-login</a>
```

how do i handle this action field?
page on successful access is http:/xx/shome.jsp

how do i get access to the new page and verify that indeed my login has worked.?

what am i doing wrong?

is it possible to to get the newpage(which opens after login success) on a webbrowser eg firefox?(as a confirmation that it indeed worked).used webbrowser module before but how do i integrate it here?

can this be done in "requests" module?

there are many posts on how to access webpages through login but i couldnt find any on how to verify that you have indeed successfully done it?

Comment: If you're doing scraping, look at Scrapy. Otherwise, are you sure that the form isn't sending some other stuff along with the username and password (some CSRF token)?

Comment: Sir,i will look at scrappy but before that i want to understand basic login.how do you search for csrf tokens??